# NoneType when I try to scrape with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with a webpage when I try to extract a table. My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://www.ismworld.org/supply-management-news-and-reports/reports/ism-report-on-business/pmi/august/'
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
data = requests.get(url, headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
t=soup.find("table", {"class": "table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive mb-4"})
print(t)
```

When I print "t", I have a None. What is wrong in the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier and give `pandas` a try.

To get all the tables, try this:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ismworld.org/supply-management-news-and-reports/reports/ism-report-on-business/pmi/august/'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, flavor='bs4')
print(df[0])
```

Sample output of the first table:

```
                     Index  ... Trend* (Months)
0       Manufacturing PMI®  ...              27
1               New Orders  ...               1
2               Production  ...              27
3               Employment  ...               1
4      Supplier Deliveries  ...              78
5              Inventories  ...              13
6   Customers’ Inventories  ...              71
7                   Prices  ...              27
8        Backlog of Orders  ...              26
9        New Export Orders  ...               1
10                 Imports  ...               3
11         OVERALL ECONOMY  ...              27
12    Manufacturing Sector  ...              27

[13 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: It's a good strategy, thanks. I only have this issue, when I run `pd.read_html(...` on mi computer I receive this valueError: "No tables found". Do you know why It's possible?